# Unit testing VueJS with axios, TypeScript template, and async functions

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, axios, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to unit test a component that makes an HTTP call in its `mounted()` hook. I'm using the template created by CLI using Typescript and Jest. My component looks something like this:

```
export default class UsrUsers extends Vue {
  private error: string = '';
  private users: User[] | null = null;

  private async mounted() {
    const url = process.env.VUE_APP_SERVICE_URL;

    try {
      const res = await axios.get<User[]>(`${url}/api/users`);
      this.users = res.data;

    } catch (ex) {
      this.error = (ex as AxiosError).message;
    }
  }
}
```

I found [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) package, and I have a test setup like this:

```
describe('Users Container', () => {
  const axiosMock = new MockAdapter(axios);
  const baseUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_SERVICE_URL;

  it('should display no user when user list is empty', async () => {
    axiosMock.onGet(`${baseUrl}/api/users`).reply(200, []);

    const wrapper = await shallowMount(UsrUsers);
    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch('no user');
  });
});
```

But, it's not working (I also tried with `jest.mock('axios')`), and I get an empty string as `wrapper.text()`.

I also tried using `$nextTick` like this:

```
it('should display no user', done => {
  // Set up axiosMock
  const wrapper = shallowMount(UsrUsers);

  wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch('no user');
    done();
  });
});
```

But this is timing out with the message `Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout`

So, how can I properly test this component?? I tried to find something on the internet, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are not replying with anything on 200 with axios mock.
`axiosMock.onGet('${baseUrl}/api/users').reply(200, []);` should probably be `axiosMock.onGet('${baseUrl}/api/users').reply(200, {data: 'no user'});`or something like that. But you got to reply with some data so your component uses it to update itself like in your example.